# how to use react navigation inside alert onpress?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

i'm using react navigation v5,

i'm trying to navigate to login screen from alert when user press Ok,
but currently not working with error >>

> can't find variable: navigation

The function is below :

```js
async function handleSubmit(navigation) {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('storage_useremail');
    if (value !== null) {
      fetch('https://xxxxxx/logout', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: value,
        }),
      }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          // console.log(res.err_code)
          if (res.err_code == '0000') {
      Alert.alert('Notice',res.message + " (" + res.err_code + ")",[{ text: 'Yes', onPress: () => navigation.navigate('Login')} ]);
          } else {
            Alert.alert("Response:  " + res.err_code + " - " + res.message);
          }
        })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
}



function HomeNavigator() {
  return (
<AppStack.Navigator mode="modal" initialRouteName="Login" screenOptions={({ route, navigation }) => ({
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#fb5b5a',
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
  },
  headerRight: () => (
    <Button
      onPress={() => handleSubmit()}
      // onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}
      title="Logout"
      color="#fff"
    />
  ),
})}>
  <AppStack.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={{
      title: 'Home',
    }}
  />
  <AppStack.Screen
    name="Memory"
    component={MemoryScreen}
    options={{
      title: 'Memory',
    }} />
</AppStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

navigation.navigate('Login') << this the part where can't navigate.

Can somebody help this?

Thanks before

Comment: Where did you use `handleSubmit ` and pass `navigation` to it?

Comment: hi i put in the headerRight. let me update the code above. thanks

Comment: You did not pass `navigation` to `handleSubmit` function. You can get it form ``headerRight: (navigation) ....` then pass it to `handleSubmit(navigation)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't pass navigation to handleSubmit

```
function HomeNavigator() {
  return (
<AppStack.Navigator mode="modal" initialRouteName="Login" screenOptions={({ route, navigation }) => ({
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#fb5b5a',
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
  },
  headerRight: () => (
    <Button
      onPress={() => handleSubmit(navigation)} // <<<<<<<<<<<< Here
      // onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}
      title="Logout"
      color="#fff"
    />
  ),
})}>
  <AppStack.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={{
      title: 'Home',
    }}
  />
  <AppStack.Screen
    name="Memory"
    component={MemoryScreen}
    options={{
      title: 'Memory',
    }} />
</AppStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onPress should be a function declaration that will be triggered when pressed

```js
onPress: () => navigation.navigate('Login')
```

Comment: if change to :

Alert.alert('Notice',res.message + " (" + res.err_code + ")",[{ text: 'Yes', onPress: () => navigation.navigate('Login')} ]);

[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')]